# Is it possible to set Ruby ENV with bash in Chef?

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a Chef recipe in which I am creating a new randomly named user using a shell script and exporting the username as a variable. Is it possible to set the same user as a session variable in Ruby? Something like...

```
ENV['CHEFUSER'] = 'echo $CHEFUSER'
```

which does not work unfortunately. Or any way to pass environment variables from bash to ruby. I need this new user to be recognized in the same recipe in which it was created.

Thanks, sorry if this has been addressed, I could not find any info on it.

Comment: I am not familiar with chef, but the following addresses setting system env variables from within a Ruby program: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561828/ruby-setting-environment-variables-using-system

Comment: Thanks.. in my case it would come down to "#{@variable}" set in bash, which is the major disconnect. I appreciate the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to ask this would have been how to set a user as a Ruby ENV. Solved with the following, for UID=501:

```
ENV['CHEFUSER'] = Etc.getpwuid(501).name
```